# How to write a LoadStore for List in hazelcast

Tags: java, hazelcast

All the examples found in the documentation are provided for map, queue and set. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think you have that possibility in Hazelcast. Only persistence I have ever seen (and used) in Hazelcast is the MapStore/MapLoader for distributed maps.

See javadoc here: http://www.hazelcast.com/docs/2.5/javadoc. And especially MapStore: http://www.hazelcast.com/docs/2.5/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/MapStore.html.

Comment: It is specifically mentioned about List. for map ,sets and queues documentation is provided.

Comment: I do not see how that's configurable. Only maps has a configurable store/loader (as far as I can see). Do you have a pointer in the documentation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26218732/is-there-a-possibility-to-keep-a-single-map-store-and-use-for-multiple-maps-in-h , Anyway to solve this ????